# How to solve the “something went wrong” error while uploading the image file?

Tags: image, solver, solution, resolve, image-file

How to solve the “something went wrong” error while uploading the image file on etcher? I have updated the  Etcher application also and then try downloading the OS image again but the same error shoes again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the format, it could be that the image viewer you are using doesn't support the file type your photo is in.